# memory leak using multiple detached threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am creating a server that creates a detached thread every time a client connects to the server.

```
    TRACE(DETAILED_TRACE,("Entered infinite loop of server.\n"));
    printf("\nThread counter = %d\n", thread_counter);
    printf("Waiting for connection...\n");

    len=sizeof(cliaddr);

    connfd=accept(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&len);
    if (connfd < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            printf("Interrupted system call ??");
        else
            error_exit(SYSTEM_ERROR, "Connection");
    }
    if(FLAG_UNSET == server_stop_flag)
    {
        printf("Connection from %s\n",
               inet_ntop(AF_INET,&cliaddr.sin_addr,buf,sizeof(buf)));

        thread_return = pthread_create((th+thread_counter), NULL
                                       ,thread_func,(void*)&connfd);
        if(thread_return)
        {
            error_exit(SYSTEM_ERROR, "Thread Creation");
        }
        else
        {
            thread_return = pthread_detach(th[thread_counter
                                               ]);
            if(thread_return)
            {
                printf("\nError code: %d\n", thread_retu
                       rn);
                error_exit(SYSTEM_ERROR, "Detatch error"
                    );
            }
        }
        thread_counter++;
        thread_counter = thread_counter%MAX_THREADS;
```

while running valgrind i keep getting this:

> ```
> ===================================================================
> 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
>    at 0x1B905301: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:176)
>    by 0x9E7364: _dlerror_run (in /lib/libdl-2.3.4.so)
>    by 0x9E6E3B: dlsym (in /lib/libdl-2.3.4.so)
>    by 0x1B9106EE: open (vg_libpthread.c:2339)
>
> LEAK SUMMARY:
>    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
>    possibly lost:   0 bytes in 0 blocks.
>    still reachable: 16 bytes in 1 blocks.
> ===============================================================
> ```

I keep getting the same leak summary no matter how many threads are created.
since the file the leak is in is a system file and not one of my own, i have implemented something in correctly. What could it be ?

I've run the same file in valgrind on another linux server now i'm getting this:

```
==12599== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 1)
==12599== malloc/free: in use at exit: 136 bytes in 1 blocks.
==12599== malloc/free: 6 allocs, 5 frees, 184 bytes allocated.
==12599== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v
==12599== searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks.
==12599== checked 10,580,680 bytes.
==12599==
==12599== 136 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 1
==12599==    at 0x4905D27: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:279)
==12599==    by 0x358500D332: _dl_allocate_tls (in /lib64/ld-2.3.4.so)
==12599==    by 0x3585F066EE: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib64/tls/libpthr
ead-2.3.4.so)
==12599==    by 0x401222: main (test36.c:81)
==12599==
==12599== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12599==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==12599==      possibly lost: 136 bytes in 1 blocks.
==12599==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==12599==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
```

Is this a problem with the server ?
FYI: line no. 81 in test.c is the pthread_create call. is there something wrong with my create call ?

Comment: What version of _dlerror_run do you have? I remember it having a one off allocation bug since at least 2004.

Comment: i dont know :/ how do i find out ?

Comment: Your new messages are pointing at the `pthread_create()` code allocating thread-local storage and not cleaning up when the thread exits.  You might need to look at how your detached threads terminate, though I don't recall any special treatment being necessary.  Have you ensured that all your threads have terminated before your main program exits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have anything to worry about.  The leak summary says:

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
still reachable: 16 bytes in 1 blocks.
```

and 'still reachable' memory has not been definitively lost, and it seems to be in system code as you identify, and it doesn't increase with number of threads, all of which adds up to "nothing to worry about" in my book.

Unless the amount of memory increases dramatically, or you can identify how it is your code that is possibly leaking memory, spend your time on other issues and not this one.

Comment: i HAVE to have zero leaks... i cant submit the code with any memory leaks whatsoever...

Comment: By my reckoning, there are no leaks - the memory in use is not 'definitely lost' and not 'possibly lost'.  It appears to be `dlsym()` that is causing the trouble; do you ever call it yourself?  If not, it is a system library issue, and you can add it to the suppression list.  If you do call `dlsym()`, can you fix the problem with `dlclose()`?

Comment: i do not call either of those functions... i've check all the mallocs and all the open calls they are all getting freed and closed... but this stupid leak wont go away...

Comment: It won't go away because it isn't your code that is leaking (even assuming it is a leak, which I don't fully accept).  Sometimes, the system libraries allocate memory and never free it, but they keep a record of where it is.  The library will reuse it if it gets the chance.  That's what the 'still reachable' tag means.  It is allocated - not leaked.  And it is outside your direct control.

Answer (score 2):

Something caught my eye when I looked at this:

```
    thread_return = pthread_create((th+thread_counter), NULL
                                   ,thread_func,(void*)&connfd);
```

It passes the address of `connfd` to another thread. How was `connfd` allocated? It is not a local variable, is it?

Comment: it is a local variable... i've allocated it as "int connfd" in main... then used "connfd=accept(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&len);" to get its value, as far as i know you can pass a local variable to a thread as an argument.

Comment: Technically you can. On practice the value of `connfd` may change before the other thread has a chance to look at it. Or it may go out of scope. In other words, when `pthread_create()` returns there is no guarantee that the other thread has started executing, only that it has been scheduled.

Answer (score -3):

It simply means that you haven't freed all your allocated memory before ending your program. Free all your alloc pointers and this warning should disappear.

Comment: that is possibly the least helpful comment ever, ofcourse i know i need to free memory, but what you failed to notice is that its not an error raised from one of my source files but from dlsym() system call which is used to implement the interface with dynamic libraries